# XPath gets very different results between google chrome's XPath Helper tool vs lxml.html

Tags: python, xpath, lxml.html

I have an XPath expression that works perfect in google chrome's XPath Helper tool.  Using this web page:
[enter link description here](https://www.yellowpages.com/washington-dc/mip/bnsf-railway-496598824)

and paste this in the xpath tool:

```
//dd[@class='open-hours']//div//span/following-sibling::text()
```

and you will get a large paragraph staring with: "For any three-day period..."

The screenshot below shows our starting element and the text we're trying to get:
[image: YellowPages.com]

Using lxml.html I start with this expression "//dd[@class='open-hours']//div" and then loop through  the div tags getting info, but in this case it's returns data from elsewhere, an address:
Washington, DC 20001

Can someone please explain why using what seems to be the same xpath in code is not outputting as expected?

```
import requests, time, socket
import lxml.html as lxml

response = requests.get('https://www.yellowpages.com/washington-dc/mip/bnsf-railway-496598824')
data = response.text
tree = lxml.fromstring(data)
stuff = tree.xpath("//dd[@class='open-hours']//div")
for elem in stuff:
    try:
        for tbl in elem:
            if tbl.tag == 'span':
                header = tbl.text
                blob = ''
                if (len(elem.xpath("//span/following-sibling::text()"))) == 1:
                    blob = elem.xpath("//span/following-sibling::text()")[0].strip()
                    print(blob)

    except Exception as detail:
        print(str(detail))
        print(str(elem.text_content().strip()))
        continue
```